# Perform a Kruskal-Wallis test in Stata

Tags: self-study

Could anyone help me perform a Kruskal-Wallis test in Stata?

I am not familiar with Kruskal-Wallis test, but I have to perform a nonparametric test, since the normality hypothesis is rejected, to confirm the results of a parametric test already performed (F-test). I have got the data already ranked in groups though I am not understanding the results.

chi-squared =   505.166 with 179 d.f.
probability =     0.0001

chi-squared with ties =   505.195 with 179 d.f.
probability =     0.0001

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear. I edited "K-Wallis" to the more standard "Kruskal-Wallis".

1. You don't need help performing a Kruskal-Wallis test in Stata, as you are quoting results. So, you found out how to do it.
2. A Kruskal-Wallis test cannot confirm a F-test (by which you presumably you mean some analysis of variance) as it is not testing the same hypothesis with the same assumptions. Moreover, if you consider the analysis of variance you carried out to be unsound, its P-value result is untrustworthy any way. Some people regard a Kruskal-Wallis test as a kind of check on analysis of variance whenever the data structure is the same, but that's at best informal.
3. The protocol for self-study questions is that you suggest an interpretation of your results, not ask us to tell you what they mean.

Comment: +1 ... though a minor comment: "*as it is not testing the same hypothesis with the same assumptions*" --- however, it can test the same hypothesis with additional assumptions to the usual ones made for the KW

Comment: @Glen_b There could be a short discussion and a long discussion of the point you raise. I'd regard the additional assumptions as usually gratuitous here.